# Time complexity of this recursive block

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

```
int recursiveFunc(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0) return i + recursiveFunc(n / i);
    return n;
}
```

I know Complexity = length of tree from root node to leaf node * number of leaf nodes, but having hard time to come to an equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is tricky, because the runtime is highly dependent on what number you provide in as input in a way that most recursive functions are not.

For starters, notice that the way that this recursion works, it takes in a number and then either

1. returns without making any further calls if the number is prime, or
2. recursively calls itself on number divided by that proper factor.

This means that in one case, the function, called on a number n, will do Θ(n) work and make no calls (which happens if the number is prime), and in the other case will do Θ(d) work and then make a recursive call on the number n / d, which happens if n is composite and is the largest divisor of n.

One useful fact we'll use to analyze this function is that given a composite number n, the smallest factor d of n is never any greater than √n. If it were, then we would have that n = df for some other factor f, and since d is the smallest proper divisor, we'd have that f ≥ d, so df > √n √ n = n, which would be impossible.

With that in mind, we can argue that the worst-case runtime of this function is O(n), and in fact that happens when n is prime. Here's how to see this. Imagine the worst-case amount of time this function can take if it ends up making a recursive call. In that case, the function will do at most Θ(√n) work (let's assume our smallest divisor is as large as possible), then recursively makes a call on a number whose size is at most n / 2 (which is the absolute largest number we could get as part of the recursive call. In that case, we'd get this recurrence relation under the pessimistic assumption that we do the maximum work possible

> T(n) = T(n / 2) + √n

This solves, by the Master Theorem, to Θ(√n), which is less work than what we'd do if we had a prime number as an input.

But what happens if, instead, we do the maximum amount of work possible for some number of iterations, and then end up with a prime number and stop? In that case, using the iteration method, we'd see that the work done would be

> n<sup>1/2</sup> + n<sup>1/4</sup> + ... + n / 2<sup>k</sup>,

which would happen if we stopped after k iterations. In this case, notice that this expression is maximized when we pick k to be as small as possible - which would correspond to stopping as soon as possible, which happens if we pick a prime number for n.

So in this sense, the worst-case runtime of this function is Θ(n), which happens for n being a prime number, with composite numbers terminating much faster than this.

So how fast can this function be? Well, imagine, for example, that we have a number of the form p<sup>k</sup>, where p is some prime number. In that case, this function will do Θ(p) work to discover p as a prime factor, then recursively call itself on the number p<sup>k-1</sup>. If you think about what this will look like, this function will end up doing Θ(p) work Θ(k) times for a total runtime of Θ(pk). And since n = p<sup>k</sup>, we'd have k = log<sub>p</sub> n, so the runtime would be Θ(p log<sub>p</sub> n). That's minimized at either p = 2 or p = 3, and in either case gives us a runtime of Θ(log n) in this case.

I strongly suspect that's the best case here, though I'm not entirely sure. But what this does mean is that

- the worst-case runtime is definitely Θ(n), occurring at prime numbers, and
- the best-case runtime is O(log n), which I'm fairly certain is a tight bound but I'm not 100% sure how to prove.